# Amazon AWS throwing 403 Forbidden after deploying django from different system

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used Ubuntu 14.04 and python 3.4 as development machine for Django.

The deployment to Amazon AWS was successful using `eb deploy` and website running without problem.

Somehow later I need to change my system and used another laptop for deployment. I copied my Virtualenv django project folder and pasted into my new system with same configuration. But now when I deploying using `eb deploy` with same security access id in AWS, it deployed succesfully but when accessing the website I am getting error as

> Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server.

But When I again deploy from old system it works but from new it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following steps and it worked from my new machine.
1. I used mysql-devel package which is for MySQL to work on AWS with django using RDS. This was configured in django.config file. I removed this configuration from it.
2. I removed .elasticbeanstalk folder.
3. Then finally ran commands : python manage.py collectstatic & python manage.py migrate
4. Then used "eb deploy". The site was successfully deployed and running.
5. Then I again put mysql-devel package in django.config file and deploy it.